# Looking for ways to optimize my counter in js/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was given the task below during an interview and wanted to know if there was a more optimal way to acheive the task...

**TASK:**

> 1. Starting a 0 Increment the count by 1 until you get to 10
> 2. Create a function where if the number is greater than 0, decrement by 2 until you get to 0. The number cannot be less than 0.
> 3. Create a function that Increments the count by 2 until you get to 10

This was my approach:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [incrementBy1, SetIncBy1] = useState(false);
  const [incrementBy2, SetIncBy2] = useState(false);
  const [decrementBy2, SetDecBy2] = useState(false);
  const [reset, setReset] = useState(false);

  const addBy1 = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  };
  const addBy2 = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 2);
  };
  const subBy2 = () => {
    setCount((count) => count - 2);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count < 10 && incrementBy1 && !reset) {
      setTimeout(addBy1, 1000);
      // setReset(false);
    }
    if (count < 10 && incrementBy2 && !reset) {
      setTimeout(addBy2, 1000);
      // setReset(false);
    }
    if (count > 0 && count % 2 === 0 && decrementBy2) {
      setTimeout(subBy2, 1000);
      setReset(false);
    }

    if (
      count > 0 &&
      !reset &&
      !incrementBy1 &&
      !incrementBy2 &&
      !decrementBy2
    ) {
      setReset(true);
    }

    if (count > 0 && reset && !incrementBy1 && !incrementBy2 && !decrementBy2) {
      setReset(false);
      setCount(0);
    }

    if (count === 0 && decrementBy2) {
      SetDecBy2(false);
      setReset(false);
    }

    if (count < 0) {
      setCount(0);
    }

    console.log(incrementBy2, reset);
  }, [count, incrementBy1, incrementBy2, decrementBy2, reset]);

  const startIncrementCounter = () => {
    if (SetIncBy2) {
      SetIncBy2(false);
    }
    if (SetDecBy2) {
      SetDecBy2(false);
    }
    SetIncBy1(true);
  };

  const startDecrementBy2 = () => {
    if (SetIncBy2) {
      SetIncBy2(false);
    }
    if (SetIncBy1) {
      SetIncBy1(false);
    }
    SetDecBy2(true);
  };

  const startIncrementBy2 = () => {
    if (SetIncBy1) {
      SetIncBy1(false);
    }
    if (SetDecBy2) {
      SetDecBy2(false);
    }
    SetIncBy2(true);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    SetIncBy1(false);
    SetIncBy2(false);
    SetDecBy2(false);
    setReset(true);
    setCount(0);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        width: "100vw"
      }}
    >
      <h1>Counter!</h1>
      <h2>{count}</h2>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
          maxWidth: 600
        }}
      >
        <button
          disabled={incrementBy1 || incrementBy2 || decrementBy2}
          onClick={startIncrementCounter}
        >
          Start Counter
        </button>
        <button disabled={count === 0} onClick={startDecrementBy2}>
          Decrement By 2
        </button>
        <button
          disabled={
            incrementBy1 || incrementBy2 || decrementBy2 || count % 2 !== 0
          }
          onClick={startIncrementBy2}
        >
          Increment By 2
        </button>
        <button
          disabled={
            (!incrementBy1 && !incrementBy2 && !decrementBy2) || count === 0
          }
          onClick={handleReset}
        >
          reset
        </button>
      </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I just wanted to know if there's a better way. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Am I missing something or the first and the third statement together is like `increment the counter by 3 if it is greater than 0 and less than 10`?

Comment: @AmirhosseinSefati No, by pressing the increment by 1 button, the increment by 2 button is disabled until it is reset